# Escaping/encoding single quotes in JSON encoded HTML5 data attributes

Tags: php, json, html, custom-data-attribute

In PHP, I use `json_encode()` to echo arrays in HTML5 data attributes.
As JSON requires - and `json_encode()` generates - values encapsulated by double quotes. I therefor wrap my data attributes with single quotes, like:

```
<article data-tags='["html5","jquery","php","test's"]'>
```

As you can see, the last tag (test's) contains a single quote, and using `json_encode()` with no options leads to parsing problems.

So I use `json_encode()` with the `JSON_HEX_APOS` parameter, and parsing is fine, as my single quotes are encoded, but I wonder: is there a downside doing it like this?

Comment: You mean downside in the meaning that it works?

Comment: I mean downside in the meaning of "unexpected side effects that hexadecimal encoding might produce"

Comment: You have not showed any code how you output something, so an answer could only be a good guess.

Comment: My question is more general than specific: I wonder, in general, what is involved in dealing with hexadecimal encoding.

Comment: @Jérémy It *should* work, as in, I can't off the top of my head think of a situation where it would not, but it's really the wrong thing to do. HTML escape any values that may break your HTML syntax, as simple as that.

Comment: *Some* characters need hex-encoding because no representation exists for those in HTML/XML, not even as entities. Not the case with your strings in question (entities exists for those w/o breaking the attribute value), but in those other cases, javascript hex encoding would be required to transport the value unbroken inside of a X(HT)ML document. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to HTML escape data echoed into HTML:

```
printf('<article data-tags="%s">',
    htmlspecialchars(json_encode(array('html5', ...)), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: +1 always use the appropriate encoding in output, the only way to go. Invalid code-points (like `\x00` would need hex-encoding according to X(HT)ML specs).

Comment: for simplicity htmlspecialchars(json_encode($arrayData), ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')

Comment: i json_encode with `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($arrayData), ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')`  how to decode?

Answer (score 13):

or use the build-in option:

```
json_encode(array('html5', ...), JSON_HEX_APOS)
```

you can check it up in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-hex-apos

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know this option. It worked very well.