# Create an Array from a single HTML5 "data-" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, custom-data-attribute

I have this HTML:

```
<section id="SSID" data-texts="'Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3'"></section>
```

I want to create an Array variable in jQuery and my jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Selection = $("#SSID").data("texts");
    var Texts = [ Selection ];

    console.log(Texts.length);
});
```

For my example, the result I expect is:

```
Texts[0] = 'Text1'
Texts[1] = 'Text2'
Texts[2] = 'Text3'
```

...and that the length of the array `Texts` is **3**.

However, what I am seeing is that the length of `Texts` is **1** and that the entire string is being loaded into `Texts[0]`:

```
Texts[0] = "'Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3'"
```

I think my problem is being caused by the `"` (quotation mark) characters. How can overcome this problem and achieve my objective?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**

**HTML :**

```
<section id="SSID" data-texts='"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"'></section>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
var Selection = JSON.parse('[' + $("#SSID").data("texts") + ']');
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/sqfq6/1/)</kbd>

or

**HTML :**

```
<section id="SSID" data-texts='"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"'></section>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
var Selection = JSON.parse($("#SSID").data("texts"));
```

---

**FYI :** But it would be better to store the actual JSON as the data attribute value. For eg : `data-texts='["Text1", "Text2", "Text3"]'` and parse it directly.

---

**UPDATE :** Or you can do it using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/map) method and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```js
var Selection = $("#SSID").data("texts").split(',').map(JSON.parse);

console.log(Selection);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="SSID" data-texts='"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"'></section>
```

Comment: Is there any way to use `data-texts=" 'a', 'b', 'c' "` format instead of `data-texts=' "a", "b", "c" '`?

Comment: @Phoenix Note that this is the technically inferior solution. Use *actual* JSON, not some string with manually added square brackets.

Answer (score 20):

`data-` attributes can contain JSON.

jQuery will automatically parse them for you, if they are syntactically valid.

```
<section id="SSID" data-texts='["Text1", "Text2", "Text3"]'></section>
```

and

```
$(function() {
    var texts = $("#SSID").data("texts");

    console.log(texts.length);  // logs "3"
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5mtre/

---

Security hint: You must encode the JSON correctly on the server.

This means that you need to do JSON encoding *and* HTML encoding, here shown examplary using PHP:

```html
<section id="SSID" data-texts="<?=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>"></section>
```

Comment: You should also add flags and encoding, see this answer. Fixed my issue
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8832570/1643487

Comment: @Tim Just for reference, can you shed light on the circumstances under which omitting `ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'` would lead to wrong results?

Comment: when you have a single qoute in your JSON data, for example: `data-texts='["Text1", "'Text2", "Text3"]'`. This wil break at `'Text2`.

Comment: You can also just do `json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_QUOT)` to change quotes to `&quot;`.

Comment: @Nicholas No, that is not enough. All this does is encode the JSON itself differently. `{"key": "value with \"quotes\"..."}` becomes `{"key": "value with \u0022quotes\u0022..."}`, which is technically the same thing. But the JSON string will still contain `<`, `>`, `&` and `"` unencoded and this will break the HTML. Preventing to HTML breakage is the whole point of `htmlspecialchars()`. General advice: Don't try to be smart about this kind of thing. Always use the proper functions. Rigorously encode for the medium you are using, layer by layer, in this case: Raw Data -> JSON -> HTML.

Comment: @Tomalak, Works for me, but you might have different requirements: https://jsbin.com/tuwazotono/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @NicholasRuunu It works because modern HTML parsers are incredibly forgiving and clever in making sense of horribly broken input. Don't let that fool you into thinking that `<div data-test="Something > something&Else < <tag>">` would *not* be horribly broken input. It is. Don't produce this kind of thing. And don't make any generalizations based on "works for me". It's either correct - or it is not. And this stuff is not.

Comment: @Tomalak, Ok, to me that's totally valid. The contents within quotes is a string and you should be able to put any string there and it should not be resolved into tags.

Comment: *"Ok, to me that's totally valid."*  - That is because you lack fundamental knowledge about how HTML works. Also, this whole thing is not a matter of personal opinions.

Comment: @Tomalak, Ok, you're just being rude. Data-attribute values are strings, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes
Could you point me to a point in the HTML spec where it says otherwise?