# PHP json_decode failed when value contains single quote (')

Tags: php, json

I cannot make json_decode() to work when the string value contains single quote (') as example below:

```
$result = "{\"message\":\"test \' \",\"report\":[{\"1\":[{\"port\":\"gsm-1.2\",\"phonenumber\":\"XXXXXXXXXXX\",\"time\":\"2016-08-31 00:22:57\",\"result\":\"success\"}]}]}";
$resp = json_decode($result, true);
echo $resp;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832528/escaping-encoding-single-quotes-in-json-encoded-html5-data-attributes

Comment: Why are you escaping it?  Just use `'`.  Also, you can't `echo` the array.

Comment: And don't build JSON strings by hand if you don't have to. Build the correct object/array and then let `json_encode()` handle the rest.

Comment: @AbraCadaver you are right. the escaping of the single quote causes the problem.

Comment: @Sammitch I don't realy build it by hand. the result came from a result from our gsm gateway api. but that specific string values causes the error of json_decode. but abracadaver pointed out it's the escaping of single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the single quote(') is skipped with slash () thus it is breaking the JSON format.

Try removing the slash and try. It should work.

You should check the code where you are generating this JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Your $result json is not in proper format so i think you need to use stripslashes() to format it and after use json_decode(). it would work :).

```
<?php
$result = "{\"message\":\"test \'\",\"report\":[{\"1\":[{\"port\":\"gsm-1.2\",\"phonenumber\":\"XXXXXXXXXXX\",\"time\":\"2016-08-  31 00:22:57\",\"result\":\"success\"}]}]}";
$result=stripslashes($result);
$resp = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($resp);
?>
```

> check on phpfiddle => http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4e7n-vjxa